# Sharing Socket instance between threads

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a multi-threaded application, where different components (running in different threads) needs to send out UDP messages. For now they all share the same Socket instance.

The socket is created as `Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)` and `socket.Send(byte[] message)` is called from the threads. Socket.Send is the only method that is called.

Is this a bad approach? I haven't seen any problems yet, but I fear that this is not the way sockets were intended to be used.

Comment: I suspect that UDP send is internally thread-safe due to synchro. within the network stack.  On the one occasion I can remember where I had to do something like this, I queued all the message objects to one UDP dispatcher thread - sure to work and easier to debug, but maybe not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the most "correct" solution is to create a method that calls the socket.send method and protect this call by using a lock or mutex. This way wikl garantee that socket object is used for once thread at a given time. You can also archieve this by using a queue.

Comment: Actually I have a wrapper class for the Socket so it is only to lock before calling Socket.Send. It seems to work the same as before, but now I do not need to worry so much.